# How to set the size of MS chart in millimetre instead of pixel in C#

Tags: c#, size, mschart

I am trying to set the size of chart object in millimetre in C# using the following code:

```
var chart = new Chart();
chart.RenderingDpiX = 300;
chart.RenderingDpiY = 300;
chart.CreateGraphics().PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
chart.Size = new Size(290, 200); // meant to be 290 millimetre not pixel
...
chart.SaveImage(@"D:\Temp\tttt.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

I expect that size of saved image be something around 290 * (300/254) = 3425 pixel, whereas the size of image is 290 pixel by 200 pixel?

I also tried to set the page unit in postPaint event using

```
private void ChartPostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
  var g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
  g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
}
```

But this does not work either! Could you please help me how to set the size of chart in millimetre or inches instead of pixel?

Comment: From the official documentation of the Chart class there is no option which says that you can use mm as unit of measurement. Did you try to create a method which would do that for you?

Comment: MM is a physical unit and only makes sense when actually printing. If you want a certain pixel size with a certain dpi resolution you can do it but on a screen it just makes no sense. Setting .[RenderingDpiX/Y](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.renderingdpix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not meant to be used by you! Best use DrawToBitmap and setResolution on the Image, then save! Also: Never use CreateGraphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `Chart()` seems that the default measurement unit is `px`.
But, you could use the `px` as an input for a method which could give you the value on `mm`.
To do so you could write:

```
private double toMM(int _px)
{
    return this._px*(300/254);
}
```

So, now you would have something like:

```
chart.Size = new Size(toMM(290), toMM(200));
```